# \includegraphics forces new page

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, scaling, includegraphics, blank-page

When I include a PDF diagram, it forces a new page, so I have one blank page and then this diagram, can somebody help me please? I need to remove that blank page.

My document looks like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[total={17cm,25cm}, top=2.0cm, bottom=1cm, left=0.0cm, right=0.0cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{total={17cm,25cm}, top=2.0cm, bottom=1cm, left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm, includefoot}
\section*{Diagram případů užití}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diagram.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting output is

[image: output result with blank page]

Comment: theres a LaTex stack exchange, might be worth getting this moved over there ?

Comment: Reduce the width of the image. It seems that the pdf is to height.

Comment: I don't think so, because it inserts blank page and on the next page it seems to be ok.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Without further information we can't help you.

Comment: There is a completely blank page inserted? Or does the `\section*` simply stands on its own? Also what do you mean with "seems to be ok"? This is not the normal behavior of `\includegraphics`, so you either doing something funny or the PDF is too large or maybe defect.

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.us/f/819/snmekobrazovky20111204v.png/)
Here you can see, what i mean by "seems to be ok". What is on site 3 i expected on site 2, but instead 2 is blank page.

Comment: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[total={17cm,25cm}, top=2.0cm, bottom=1cm, left=0.0cm, right=0.0cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{total={17cm,25cm}, top=2.0cm, bottom=1cm, left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm, includefoot}

\section*{Diagram případů užití}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{diagram.pdf}

\end{document}`

Comment: You can edit the question to add the additional link and code.

Comment: The section + the image is to large. As no page break is allowed after the section title, TeX moves both to the next page, realize that there isn't enough place there too and then TeX gives up, puts both on the page and complains in the log about an overfull vbox. If the image is only a bit too large you can use `\enlargethispage{1cm}` to add a bit space on the page.

Comment: Your minimal only shows one image, whereas the images show two. Me thinks it is caused by the `newgeometry`, which always issues a new page.

Comment: BTW: You don't need package `a4wide` while you are using `geometry`. And [l2tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english) says: _a4.sty. a4wide.sty: Do not use these two packages any longer._

Answer (score 12):

The image is too large to fit on current page, because there is not much place left. It is also too large to fit on a page of its own, therefore moving to the next (last?) page, where it is apparently placed using some emergency rule even if it doesn't fit there either.

You should include the image using the following options instead:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{diagram.pdf}
```

This tries to scale it to the textwidth but not larger than the textheight while keeping the aspect-ratio.

To allow enough space for a caption you should reduce the height a little, e.g. either take only `.9\textheight` or subtract two lines or so from it.

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip\relax,keepaspectratio]{diagram.pdf}
```

From the look of it it might also belong into a `figure` environment. There you should add a `\centering` before the `\includegraphics` to have it centered.

Comment: If it shall fit on the same page as the section title, a bit smaller than the `\textheight` might be appropriate.

Comment: I tried what you wrote and still not working. I must probably use scale parameter and make image smaller :(.

Comment: @designerrr you can also use `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{diagram.pdf}` to reduce the size

Comment: you can also try `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`