# Remove blank pages between figures in appendix?

Tags: appendix

I am trying to make an Appendix with a few figures. My problem is that LaTeX inserts a blank page between some of the figure and I can't figure out why. It feels lika I have tried everything.

[image]

Here is a short example of how the code in the appendix section looks like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{appendix,float}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bilagor}
\appendix
% ToC of the appendices

\section{Utförande: forskningsöversikt}
\label{appendix:A}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{Bilagor/Bilaga1nyy.png}
\end{figure}

%Kommer bli bilaga B
\section{Kostnadskalkyl}
\label{appendix:B}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Bilagor/kostnad.png}
\end{figure}
\section{Lathund för kalibrering av friktionsmätare}
\label{appendix:C}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=-90]{Bilagor/BilagaC1.PNG}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=-90]{Bilagor/BilagaC2.PNG}
\end{figure}
```

So greatful if anyone can help me!

Comment: Likely because the figures are too large, see [errors - Blank pages getting inserted between figures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286037/blank-pages-getting-inserted-between-figures)

Comment: And if that's not the problem, we're going to have trouble helping you because we don't have those images.  In that case, can you recreate the problem with `\includegraphics{example-image-a}`, which we do have?  (And extend your code to a complete example by including the `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\begin\end{document}`.)

Comment: IIRC, \section and figure don't play well together.  You might try putting \section inside figure [p].